# Redirecting same page again

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

I have page register.php, which is used to get user informations, after completion of form, it submits to an-other page, post.php.

post.php performs two actions, it adds incoming data to 2 locations in order,  1.php and 2.php, so the flow of data is

```
 register.php -->post.php --> 1.php -->2.php -->register.php?value='abc'
```

once data is sent to both the locations, again register.php is loaded but this time page apears in browser like

```
http://www.example.com/register.php?value='abc'
```

how can i redirect this page to welcome.php? the new flow will be

```
register.php -->post.php --> 1.php -->2.php -->register.php?value='abc' -->welcome.php
```

as for as such a strange flow is concerned, that quite learning things, and there is no problem with it, i am caught at the last step, when i have to redirect the page to welcome.php..

how can I do it?

Comment: Why can't you use http redirect as you did in previous pages? `header('Location: ')` doesn't work? Meta redirect? (google it)

Comment: previously i did used a form to send data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you use a session variable instead of using GET on the register.php page?

```
if(isset($_SESSION['value']){
    header('Location:');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several options, using [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) with `Location:` (one of examples in manual):

```
header( 'Location: welcome.php');
// Or with all parameters:
header( 'Location: welcome.php', true, 301);
```

Or [meta redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_redirect):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
```

Or [javascript redirect](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php):

```
window.location.href = 'welcome.php'
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but let me know it, if i use any of these 3, whenever the page will be loaded, it will be redirected to welcome.php, Am i true?

Comment: just an heads up... it might be usefull to do header( 'Location: welcome.php', true,301); to avoid errors

Comment: @NewBee whenever you use them page will be redirected (the first one, `header()`, will actually stop php script for completing)

Comment: i want to check 'http://www.example.com/register.php?value='abc'' then i want to redirect, not always

Comment: @NewBee `if( whatever){ header('Location: welcome');} else { not so much redirected}`

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want

```
if(str_pos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"2.php") > 0){
   header( 'Location: welcome.php', true,301);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "2.php") is it okay? or i have to use the complet url?

Comment: str_pos is best! it will search all the address for that string. Either this or preg_match but this is easier!